# ASP.Net Razor view - show byte data of document, within view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a razor view, and in the viewmodel, I have an `IEnumerable` of documents.

What I am wanting to do, is retrieve the `byte` array for the document, and then have it displayed in the razor view.

```
foreach (var document in Model.documents)
{
  <div src="@Url.Action("GetDocument", "Document", new {Id = document.Id})"/>
}
```

The above is what I have in the view, and the below is the code for the `GetDocument` method:

```
public void GetDocument(int id)
{
   var document = _documentRepository.Get(id);
   Response.ContentType = document.ContentType;
   Response.Write(document.data);
}
```

Is what I am trying to achieve possible?

Comment: What document are you trying to render? If it is pdf only then you can try to use `<frame></frame>` or `<embed></embed>` tag instead of `<div></div>`. If you want to render other file types then I think you need some third party tool for document viewer.

Comment: I was looking at rendering a `.txt` but, I will use a PDF for the time being, and see if I can get it to show. Thanks for the info.

Comment: if I understand it correctly, you want to display a text file within a razor page?

Comment: It could be any document, a PDF, .doc, .docx, .txt. I have kind of given up, at the moment, and have approached it a different way.